# Where is the facebook graph api documentation for searching anything

Tags: facebook-graph-api

While researching I found that it's possible to research things on facebook using the `/search` path. However I cannot find any documentations on how to use this functionality.

I already know that the graph api documentation is https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

I already looked at the places search documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/places/search

Nevertheless, what I would like to know is all parameters that I can use for the `graph.facebook.com/search`

For the moment I know that I can use `q`, and `type` with `user`,`page`, or `group`.

Where I should look for the complete documentation about this path?

**Edit: Solved**

Look at the comment by CBroe 13

> It looks like Facebook has recently removed the documentation for this, maybe temporary, and probably because of recent "privacy breaches". You can check out this older copy on https://web.archive.org/web/20170104062957/https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#search – CBroe 13 hours ago

Comment: It looks like Facebook has recently removed the documentation for this, maybe temporary, and probably because of recent "privacy breaches". You can check out this older copy on https://web.archive.org/web/20170104062957/https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#search

Comment: Thanks! This is want I was looking for ;)

Answer (score 4):

Per
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/04/facebook-api-platform-product-changes/

> Search API
>
> Deprecated: Support for finding pages, groups, events, users using
>   search.
>
> It's not deprecated, it's discontinued.

While they say it is "deprecated", it has been terminated and so far I have not found anything that speaks of a replacement. Here is another announcement:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#search-4-4

FYI, I have posted a comment on the Facebook Developers Community page, hoping to elicit some kind of response from Facebook:

https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/permalink/1742432315800275/

Answer (score 0):

You can find detailed Graph API documentation on the developers page

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/

Details about Search API is also available here.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/places/search

Comment: I already know these two pages. However I don't only want to search for places, but also users, groups, etc.

I would like to know all the parameters that I can use for the `/search` path