# Alternative to use facebook graph api /search endpoint with object type "pages"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

recently FB has been doing some major changes, from which they had restricted all data access to the /search query for type="pages" (groups, events, and one other object...)

Can anyone figure this out and help me with an alternative/workaround to find pages and page details using q="keyword"?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: there is no alternative, see breaking changes: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#search-4-4

Answer (score 1):

You can find more information about Facebook disabling the /search API endpoint here: [Where is the facebook graph api documentation for searching anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49573223/where-is-the-facebook-graph-api-documentation-for-searching-anything)